# Increase font-size to full width of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

What would be the best way to increase the size of a font to make it take full width of a screen or rather view width? A good example is the one gumroad are using: https://gumroad.com/
However they seem to have used it as an image rather than normal text, is it possible to do it with just normal text?

Comment: Are you dealing with static or dynamic text?

Comment: Just static text, I'm looking at it in way that I wouldn't have trouble making it responsive as compared to an image which would be much easier to do e.g. adding the tried and tested max-width: 100% and height auto properties, hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: Yeah pretty much use the above linked question. But short answer would be set the `font-size` in `vw` units and just experiment with the exact value until it's the width you need (will depend on the font-family and content). With a monospace font you can calculate the `font-size` dynamically as `100vw` divided by the number of characters.

Comment: Yeah that was useful, thanks. So my solution came to this: `font-size: calc((100vw - 4.5rem) / 7)`, added a `white-space: nowrap` since my text was a bit longer, and some padding on each ends of the text. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in gumroad its not a text its an image
but if you want to control your font size you can use
`font-size: clamp(min size , 2vw, max size)`
for example `font-size: clamp(14px, 2vw, 20px)`
you can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()